# LEFT JOIN and MAX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql request like that :

```
SELECT *, MAX(dateFin)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.id = t2.idUtl
GROUP BY t2.dateFin
ORDER BY t1.dateCreation
limit 0,10
```

I have this tables :

```
t1                         t2   
id   dateCreation          id   idUtl   dateFin
1    2015-02-25            1    1       2015-01-10
2    2015-02-22            2    1       2014-09-12
3    2015-06-20            3    3       2014-08-23
```

So with my request i have this result:

```
t1.id   dateCreation   t2.id   idUtl   dateFin
3       2015-06-20     3       3       2014-08-23
1       2015-01-10     1       1       2015-01-10
```

My problem is that i also want this line

```
t1.id   dateCreation   t2.id   idUtl   dateFin
2       2015-02-22     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I try something with another SELECT in my request but it didn't work and i don't think it's a really good idea.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  The `limit` suggests MySQL.

Comment: Because you're doing a left join the values that aren't matched will only be associated with t1. FULL OUTER JOIN is what you're looking for.If MySQL check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: @FirebladeDan the row he's missing is part of t1 though...

Comment: @Alex - No it's t2. The id's don't match so t2 is not returned

Comment: @FirebladeDan correct, but neither is t1 in his example. A LEFT JOIN will return all rows in the left table (t1), so something else is removing row t1.id=2 from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT t1.*, MAX(t2.dateFin)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.id = t2.idUtl
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.dateCreation
limit 0, 10;
```

I think the problem is your `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution :

```
SELECT  * from t1
left JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.idUtl
and date_fin=(select  MAX(t2.date_fin) from t2 where t1.id = t2.id_candidat )
ORDER BY t1.dateCreation
limit 0,10
```